# Undefined value using Laravel in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, laravel

The following code should display the availability of the selected record in the `alert` call, but it always results in `undefined`. How should the `availability` value be computed?

```
{!! Form::open(array('url'=>'admin/products/toggle-availability', 'class'=>'form-inline update-form', 'data-recordid'=>$product->id))!!}
{!! Form::select('avail', array('1'=>'In Stock', '0'=>'Out of Stock'), $product->availability) !!}
{!! Form::submit('Update') !!}
{!! Form::close() !!}

<script> type="text/javascript">
           $(document).ready(function(){
               $(".update-form").submit(function(s){
                   s.preventDefault();
                   var recordID = $(this).data('recordid');
                   var availability = $('input[name=avail]').val();
                   alert(availability);
               });
           });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I already solve :)`

View

```
               <select id ="availability">
```

Jquery

```
               var availability = $('#availability option:selected').val();
```

`